# How to read Mahout negative classification results

Tags: hadoop, vector, classification, mahout

I'm using Mahout 0.8, and after classification using NaiveBayes i get results:

```
FileName       Category    Score
1000221        male        -13059.636009313888
1000378369     female      -6660.011396382251
10004522       male        -20388.73959786186
```

How to Read this Score? I want to get accuracy for each FileName. In code I have:

```
// some code...
vector.setQuick(wordId, tfValue);

// some code...
Vector resultVector = classifier.classifyFull(vector);
    double bestScore = -Double.MAX_VALUE;
    for(Element element: resultVector.all()) {
        int categoryId = element.index();
        double score = element.get();
        if (score > bestScore) {
            bestScore = score;
            bestCategoryId = categoryId;
        }
    }
    return bestScore;
```